# Jenkins Groovy Sandbox In-ProcessApproval

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins I am facing an issue as when in pipeline job if Use Groovy Sandbox is unchecked then job should not run
it should come for approval to jenkins administrator.

but currently it is happening reverse way.

If Use Groovy Sandbox is checked : It is asking for approval of jenkins administrator
If Use Groovy Sandbox is uncheck : Pipeline job is getting executing.

can you please help the same how i can achieve the same.

is there any configuration i need to adopt it.

BR,
GauravS

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279361/joerg-s : Can you please help the same

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Groovy sandbox", then you don't have to approve all the script, but you might need to approve some signatures that Jenkins marks as dangerous.
If you run a groovy script without the sandbox, you will need to approve it once. After you've approved, the script will be executed without approval. At least, until you modify the script, so to Jenkins it will look like a new script.